# Global variable value is not reflected across functions

Tags: global-variables, robotframework

I want to calculate the cumulative time which gets updated across different functions.

Test Case file

```
*** Settings ***
Suite Setup         Pre_Execution_Steps
Suite Teardown      Post_Execution_Steps
Library             DateTime
Library             Extended Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Test Case 1
    Function A
```

Resource File

```
*** Settings ***
Library             DateTime
Library             ExtendedSelenium2Library

*** Keywords *** 
Pre_Execution_Steps
     Set Global Variable    ${WAIT_TIME}    00:00:00.000

Function A:
     ${WAIT_TIME}=    Add Time To Time    ${WAIT_TIME}    00:00:02.001    result_format=timer           
     Log ${WAIT_TIME}
     ${WAIT_TIME}=    Add Time To Time    ${WAIT_TIME}    00:00:02.001    result_format=timer
     Log ${WAIT_TIME}

Post_Execution_Steps
     Log    Wait time is ${WAIT_TIME}
```

When i execute the test case, global variable ${WAIT_TIME} value gets updated inside the Function A. But ${WAIT_TIME} value is not reflected in Post_Execution_Steps though it is global variable. It prints the default value 00:00:00.000

Any inputs/suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that within `Function A:`, `${WAIT_TIME}` is treated as local once it is set to a new value. To see a change to the global variable you need to call `Set global variable` inside `Function A:`.